# Limit для подчиненных таблиц в запросе

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица постов и комментариев к постам.
Задача, вытащить два последних комментария к первым 10 постам.

Answer (score 1):

А в чём сложность?

Делаете запрос на основе комментариев, джойните к ним посты, после чего сортируете это дело по постам в обратном порядке, и по комментариям в противоположном. Ну и лимитете это двумя записями?